# Retrofit @DELETE

Tags: android, retrofit2

why can't I use `@DELETE` with `@Url` Parameter like this

```
@DELETE
Call<ServerResponse> deleteAbsence(@Path("id") int absenceId , @Url String url);

Url passed ="././deleteAbsence/{id}"
```

**Stack trace**

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Path can only be used with relative url on @DELETE (parameter #2)
                                                                        for method WebApiInterface.deleteAbsence
                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:752)
                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:743)
                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:761)
                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(ServiceMethod.java:393)
                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameter(ServiceMethod.java:336)
                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:204)
                                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
                                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
```

Comment: Post error message or stack trace.

Comment: I had solved the issue by appending id to the 
Url passed ="././deleteAbsence/?id=5"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use   `@Query("id").`

```
@DELETE
Call<ServerResponse> deleteAbsence(@Query("id") int absenceId , @Url String url);
```

Comment: This works for me.
But I have to mention that `@path` may work, this depends on your backend implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters with `@Path` annotation replaces the provide value in the path supplied in the `@DELETE` annotation.

If any of your method parameter is annotated with `@Path` annotation, you must provide a relative path as a parameter in the `@DELETE` annotation.

Set relative path as a parameter in `@DELETE` annotation, not in the method.

```
@DELETE("././deleteAbsence/{id}")
Call <ServerResponse> deleteAbsence(@Path("id") int absenceId);
```

Comment: I know that I can use this way but for some reasons I need to use the way I posted